# Select de registros que pertenezcan a un tipo de planta

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure, modelorelacional

Estoy atascado intentando hacer un procedimiento almacenado,
Su funcionalidad es utilizarlo para un filtro de busqueda.

El filtro contiene una cadena de texto para buscar el nombre de la planta y una lista desplegable de seleccion multiple.

Pongo un ejemplo de uso:
Cadena de texto: "Borraja" ; Tipos: Element, Indication.

La base de datos es la siguiente:
[image: Base de datos]

De momento, lo que tengo es:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_busqueda
    @param nvarchar (255),
    @param_t1 nvarchar (2),
    @param_t2 nvarchar (2),
    @param_t3 nvarchar (2),
    @param_t4 nvarchar (2),
    @param_t5 nvarchar (2)
as
if @param_t5 IS NULL AND @param_t4 IS NULL AND @param_t3 IS NULL and @param_t2 IS NULL and @param_t1 IS NULL

    select DISTINCT p.pl_name, p.pl_id
    from plant as p
    join plant_relation as pr
        on p.pl_id = pr.pl_id
    where p.pl_name LIKE '%'+@param+'%'

else
if @param_t5 IS NULL AND @param_t4 IS NULL AND @param_t3 IS NULL and @param_t2 IS NULL

    select DISTINCT p.pl_name, p.pl_id
    from plant as p
    join plant_relation as pr
        on p.pl_id = pr.pl_id
    where p.pl_name LIKE '%'+@param+'%' AND pr.target_type = @param_t1

else
if @param_t5 IS NULL AND @param_t4 IS NULL AND @param_t3 IS NULL

    select DISTINCT p.pl_name, p.pl_id
    from plant as p
    join plant_relation as pr
        on p.pl_id = pr.pl_id
    where p.pl_name LIKE '%'+@param+'%' AND pr.target_type = @param_t1 AND pr.target_type = @param_t2

else
if @param_t5 IS NULL AND @param_t4 IS NULL

    select DISTINCT p.pl_name, p.pl_id
    from plant as p
    join plant_relation as pr
        on p.pl_id = pr.pl_id
    where p.pl_name LIKE '%'+@param+'%' AND pr.target_type = @param_t1 AND pr.target_type = @param_t2 AND pr.target_type = @param_t3

else
if @param_t5 IS NULL

    select DISTINCT p.pl_name, p.pl_id
    from plant as p
    join plant_relation as pr
        on p.pl_id = pr.pl_id
    where p.pl_name LIKE '%'+@param+'%' AND pr.target_type = @param_t1 AND pr.target_type = @param_t2 AND pr.target_type = @param_t3 AND pr.target_type = @param_t4

else

    select DISTINCT p.pl_name, p.pl_id
    from plant as p
    join plant_relation as pr
        on p.pl_id = pr.pl_id
    where p.pl_name LIKE '%'+@param+'%' AND pr.target_type = @param_t1 AND pr.target_type = @param_t2 AND pr.target_type = @param_t3 AND pr.target_type = @param_t4 AND pr.target_type = @param_t5
```

Un ejemplo de lo que quiero:

Datos de entrada:

@param = 'bo'

@param_t1 = 'EL'

@param_t2 = 'PR'

Datos de salida:
Todas las plantas que contengan 'bo' en su nombre y que en la tabla plant_relation tengan registros de target_type 'EL' y 'PR'

Comment: Consulta base.. que clase de where es ese? me lo puedes explicar?

Comment: pues empieza con condiciones mas grandes y si no se cumplen, pasa a la siguiente condicion, ahora lo he escrito asi... edito el inicio

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, podrías poner un ejemplo de que datos tienes de entrada y que esperas recibir de salida.

Comment: Listo, lo siento, pero no es muy facil de explicar @EduardoJaramilloLicea

Comment: Así como veo tu código debería de funcionar, lo que no me agrada mucho es eso de @param_tn, ya que si agregas mas opciones tienes que agregar  mas parámetros, lo que yo haría en tu caso es mandar todas las propiedades en una cadena separada por , y la consulta hacerla con un  `pr.target_type IN (STRING_SPLIT ('EL, PR',','))`